# Effect of gauge transformation on connection 1-form of a principal connection

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $(P,\pi,M,G)$ be a principal fibration, $A$ a principal connection on $P$ (i.e. $\forall p \in P, T_pP = A_p \oplus V_p$), $\omega$ the connection 1-form of $A$, $f$ a gauge transformation of $P$, $A \cdot f = f^{-1}(A)$ the right action of $Gauge(P)$ the gauge group on the affine space of principal connections on $P$,
$\omega^f$ the connection 1-form of $f^{-1}(A)$.

In Andrei Teleman's book "introduction to Gauge Theory" (in french), there is the following formula (without any proof) for the effect of a gauge transformation of the connection 1-form of a principal connection :

$\omega^f = f^* \omega = \omega +  \theta^{-1}(d^A \theta)$, where :

- $\theta : P \to G$ corresponds to $f$ via the isomorphism $Gauge(P) \simeq \Omega^{0}_{Int}(P,G)$ (this last space being the $Int$-equivariant applications $P \to G$) and $\theta$ being defined by $\forall p \in P, f(p) = p \cdot \theta(p)$,
- $d^A \theta$ is the exterior covariant differentiation associated to $A$ (i.e. $d^A \theta(X) = T_p \theta(pr^A X)$ for $x \in T_pP$,
- and the 1-form $\theta^{-1}(d^A \theta) \in \Omega^{0}_{Ad}(P,\mathfrak{g})$ is defined for $p \in P$ and $X \in T_pP$ by
  $(\theta^{-1}(d^A \theta)_p (X) = T_{\theta(p)} L_{\theta(p)^{-1}} \circ T_p \theta (pr^A X) = \omega_{mc}(T_p \theta (pr^A X))$, where $\omega_{mc}$ is the Maurer-Cartan 1-form on $G$.

$\omega^f = f^* \omega$ is OK, and I can demonstrate the whole formula for vertical tangent vector $X \in V_pP$. But I can't for $X$ horizontal.

I think that this formula could even be proved by supposing $P$ trivial, i.e. $P = U \times G$, with $U$ open set of $M$, and the connection $A$ trivial. But even in this case I can't prove the whole formula.

And I can't find either books or pdf with a clean proof.

Any help ?

Comment: I think there is some assumption on the principal bundle here, or you made a typo: The first term should generally be of the form $\operatorname{Ad}(\theta^{-1})\omega$, unless you take your gauge group to be Abelian. A full proof is given in section 5.4, theorem 5.25 of [these notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~hamilton/GaugeTheoryLecture.pdf).

Comment: Well, I checked again, if there is a typo it is in the book. But I am not sure there is a typo anyway : with the $Ad(\theta^{-1})$ you refer to the transformation formula for the \emph{local} connection 1-forms défined on $M$. My formula refers to the 1-form defined on $P$... And thanks a lot for the reference to the notes, it covers alomost all the suject of my memoir and seems pretty detailed.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it could be that I misread your question (lots of definition...).

Comment: But in fact I think you are right, my question is the theorem 5.27 in the reference you gave me, and the first part of the formula is $Ad(\theta^{-1}) \circ \omega + ...$, so my book must be wrong. Thanks again for the Mark Hamilton notes ref.

Comment: @Danu Hi! I am also struggling to understand the effect of Gauge transformation on connection 1-form of a principal bundle. But I am not able to access the link of the  notes you mentioned. Its  showing "You don't have permission to access /~hamilton/GaugeTheoryLecture.pdf on this server." It would be very helpful if you kindly advice me (how to resolve the issue) or send the pdf by some other link.. My email id is adittyachaudhuri15@iisertvm.ac.in.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These notes have by now turned into a book (by Hamilton), called Mathematical Gauge Theory. It can be found here: https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319684383

Comment: @Danu Thanks a lot!